# Using a loop versus getting a specific index in a try/except

Tags: loops, python

For a project I'm working on I am processing lots of deeply nested dict-and-list data structures. Often I find myself doing a lookup that I expect to return a list with a single member. Lookups may fail outright, or simply return zero results, so I could write code like this:

```
try:
    value_I_need = lookup_results[0]
except IndexError:
    # handle lookup failure, keep going
```

But lately I've been wondering if it would be more future-proof to write a loop, initially assuming it only happens zero or one times:

```
value_I_need = None
for value_I_need in lookup_results:
    break
if value_I_need is None:
    # handle lookup failure, keep going
```

(I say "future-proof" because I may want to re-write or generalize this code to handle lookups with more than one result in them.) Is there anything inherently unpythonic, wrong or slower about either of these two approaches?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The builtin function `next()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#next) does exactly that:

```
a = ()
b = [1, 2, 3]
print next(iter(a), "empty") # prints "empty", as a doesn't give any values.
print next(iter(b), "empty") # prints 1, the 1st value of b
```

Comment: `next()` needs an iterator, so the way you have it written won't work. However, you can just wrap the list in `iter()`, e.g. `next(iter(a), "empty")`

Answer (score 0):

Why the `for`? It could be more clearly put:

```
if value_I_need not in lookup_results:
    print "I need it but it ain't there"
```

Put another way, you will not get a sequence from

```
for x in y:
    break
```

if `y` is a sequence type, `x` will be the first element; for a dict type, it will be the (random) key of the first element. Whatever `x` was bound to before the `for` it won't be afterwards. That is:

```
x = 5
for x in range(10):
     break
```

will bind 0 to `x` and any fiveness it has in the first line has no effect on the second.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple and clear.

```
if len(lookup_results) == 1:
    result = lookup_results[0]
    # ...
else:
    # ...
```

Any performance difference here - positive or negative - will be microscopic and it conveys much more clearly your intent.

If you need to refactor later, having it written any of these ways will have no significant impact on the time you spend doing so (unless, of course, you can't tell what the code is doing).